# Why does the output change so drastically just because of the change in location of the statement in the while loop?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements, statements

Well, while trying to understand the total concept of the while loop, I came across this..

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    int x = 1;
    System.out.println("Before the loop");

    while(x < 4) {
        x = x + 1;
        System.out.println("In the loop");
        System.out.println("Value of loop x is " + x);
    }

    System.out.println("This is after the loop");

}
```

Here the output was

```
Before the loop
In the loop
Value of loop x is 2
In the loop
Value of loop x is 3
In the loop
Value of loop x is 4
This is after the loop
```

When I changed the position of the statement like this,

```
    public static void main (String[] args) {

    int x = 1;
    System.out.println("Before the loop");

    while(x < 4) {
        System.out.println("In the loop");
        System.out.println("Value of loop x is " + x);
        x = x + 1;
    }

    System.out.println("This is after the loop");

}
```

The output was,

```
Before the loop
In the loop
Value of loop x is 1
In the loop
Value of loop x is 2
In the loop
Value of loop x is 3
This is after the loop
```

Please explain to me why the output changes so drastically just by changing the location of that one statement.

Any help would be appreciated... I'm a learner aiming high ;)

Comment: You are printing the value of `x`, so incrementing the value of `x` before or after the println statement makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have essentially this:

```
x = 1
x = x + 1 // X=2
print x   // X=2
--> and then to next loop
```

and

```
x = 1
print x    // X=1 
x = x + 1  // X=2
--> and then to next loop
```

So, that's really not drastic change, it's +1 to the values, because you do it before the printing vs after the printing